# How to prove this statement about this relation:

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $p$ be a prime. On $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ we define the relation $\sim$ as $a\sim b\iff [\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}: p^n|a \iff p^n|b]$. Prove that $[\forall x,y \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}: x\sim x^2 \wedge y\sim y^2]\rightarrow x\sim y$. I thought that $x\sim x^2$ for all $x$, is this true? And how do I prove this statement?

Comment: Take e.g. $x=5$. If $5 \sim 5^2$ that would imply, since $5^2|5^2$, that also $5^2|5.$ So it seems the only case of $x \sim x^2$ would be $x=1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x \sim x^2$ is not true for all $x$ - for example, $p \not \sim p^2$ (consider $n = 2$ in the condition).

In fact, if $p | x$ then, if $k$ is the largest $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $p^k | x$, we have that $p^{2k} | x^2$ and $p^{2k} \not | x$, hence $x \not \sim x^2$.

If, however, $p \not | x$ then also $p \not | x^2$, and hence $x \sim x^2$.

So $x \sim x^2$ if and only if $p \not | x$.

If $p \not | x$ and $p \not | y$, then it's clear from the definition that $x \sim y$.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not true that $x \sim x^2$ for all $x$. For example let $x=p$. Then $p^2 | x^2$ but $p^2 \not | x $.

Regarding the actual proof, here is a little hint: Is it possible that $p | x $ and $x \sim x^2$?